# Generate list of URL paths that can match a regular expression (or similar)

Tags: regex, delphi

Say your program can imports URL paths for seeding a crawl.

A user wants to define a pattern that should function a see - e.g.

```
http://example\.com/mypage-[0-9][0-9][0-9]?/jump(suit|er)/
```

Could just be a simplified version of regex syntax if need to be - but something like above would be required for the user to enter.

From the above my software would then need to **generate** a long list like:

```
http://example.com/mypage-0/jumpsuit/
http://example.com/mypage-0/jumper/
http://example.com/mypage-1/jumpsuit/
http://example.com/mypage-1/jumper/
...
http://example.com/mypage-998/jumper/
http://example.com/mypage-999/jumper/
```

Is there anything around for Delphi that can do what I want? Or am I missing an obvious way at achieving what I want that does not require to write a regex parser from scratch :)

Comment: I do not intend to "match" but to "generate" strings? I do not see anything in TRegEx that can do that

Comment: Aha, now I see what you want. So if the user won't be careful with the input pattern, it can take millions of years to get the result :)

Comment: @Victoria Yes indeed - I may want to limit output to e.g. max 1-100K (the crawler itself can handle crawling million+ unique URLs, so it would not be unusual as such to need importing a bunch of URLs. Some people may prefer that compared to having the crawler spend time "discovering" the important pages in a website)

Comment: A regular expression defines a _language_. You're looking to generate all strings that exist in that language. The list can be infinite. A quick Google search yields [regldg](https://regldg.com/), which is unrelated to Delphi. You could certainly just run it from your program.

Comment: @RobKennedy I mention regular expressions because 1) my users *may* have a basic understanding of it already 2) I am hoping some may have had the same thought as me :) I will check the link you posted!

Comment: I once had to do something like this (generate patterned URLs for crawling a site for files to download). I defined my own syntax for the patterns, and it was quite flexible. Too bad I lost that code a few years ago :-(